# GUI calculate button coding error in java

Tags: java

Okay, first of all the project I am working on has two packages, first is murach.business which contains invoiceCalculations.java Second is murach.forms which contain InvoiceForm.java(JFrame) and SwingValidator.java

I need to add an event handler for the actionPerformed event of the Calculate button. Add code to this event handler that gets the customer type and subtotal from the form, uses the calculateDiscountPct method in the InvoiceCalculations class to calculate the the discount percent based on those values, calculates the discount amount and total, and formats and displays the values on the form.

The form has 5 rows for instance first customer type, subtotal, discount percent, discount amount and total and below that is calculate and exit button.

Here is the stack trace:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "R"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at murach.forms.InvoiceForm.calculateButtonActionPerformed(InvoiceForm.java:183)
    at murach.forms.InvoiceForm.access$300(InvoiceForm.java:15)
    at murach.forms.InvoiceForm$4.actionPerformed(InvoiceForm.java:81)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6382)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6147)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:663)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:661)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 25 seconds)
```

So far I am getting error when i hit calculate button for my code. This is my current code, could you tell me what changes i need to make to code and why?

```
private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
      // TODO add your handling code here:
   double c = Double.parseDouble(customertypeTextField.getText());
   double s = Double.parseDouble(subtotalTextField.getText());
   pct d = Percent.parsepct(discountpercentTextField.getText());
   double a = Double.parseDouble(discountamountTextField.getText());
   double total = InvoicCalculations.calculateTotal(c, s, d);
   NumberFormat currecny = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
   totalTextField.setText(currency.format(total));
}
```

Comment: By the way I have written that CODE. Its not copy and paste job.

Comment: The stacktrace would be useful but from what i see from the code you might have NumberFormatException when parsing the input. If so you should surround the parsing with a try and catch

Comment: Which currency do you implement?

Comment: Using floating-point (Double) for currency values is a VERY BAD THING.  You will be chasing rounding and precision errors forever.  Switch to BigDecimal and don't look back.

Comment: I have added stack trace

Answer (score 1):

One of the textfields contains a letter, causing `Double.parseDouble` to fail because it is not valid. From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29):

> Throws:
>
> ```
> NullPointerException - if the string is null
>
> NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable double.
> ```

To prevent this, you can:

- ensure that when you hit the calculate button, the fields only contain valid data.  You can do this by using an [InputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html).
- or verify before parsing that the input is valid, and display a popup or an error message if it isn’t.

Others have mentioned it, and it is important enough to be stressed here: [do not use `Double` for representing money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).